# Can't figure out how to return the correct values in SQL

Tags: sql

DEPARTMENT( deptnum , descrip, instname, deptname, state, postcode)

ACADEMIC( acnum , deptnum*, famname, givename, initials, title)

PAPER( panum , title)

AUTHOR( panum*, acnum* )

FIELD( fieldnum , id, title)

INTEREST( fieldnum*, acnum* , descrip)

I need to solve the following questions,

Write an SQL query to create a View that displays the title and surname of each
academic and how many papers they have written. If an academic have not written any
papers, then a “0” should be displayed against their name.

And also,

Display a list of academics that have collaborated with another academic on more than
one paper. List individual pairs of academics on each line. List only their academic
numbers. Do not list duplicate pairs. (e.g 56,113 and 113,56 are duplicate pairs).

For the first one, this is what I have until now,

```
SELECT A.ACNUM, COUNT(*)
FROM ACADEMIC A JOIN AUTHOR AU ON A.ACNUM = AU.ACNUM JOIN PAPER PA ON AU.PANUM = PA.PANUM
WHERE AU.PANUM = PA.PANUM
GROUP BY A.ACNUM
ORDER BY A.ACNUM;
```

It successfully displays all the academics who wrote papers and also outputs how many papers they wrote, however, I can't seem to figure out how to output those who haven't written any papers.

On the second question, I was able to display people who worked together with each other, however couldn't figure out how to make them, this is how far I got, it displays people who have worked together.

```
select distinct a1.acnum, a2.acnum
from academic a1, author au1, academic a2, author au2
where a1.acnum=au1.acnum
and a2.acnum=au2.acnum
and au1.panum = au2.panum
and a1.acnum < a2.acnum
order by a1.acnum;
```

Expect it to output the required values

Comment: For those without change your inner join to a left.  You want ALL Acedemics regardless if they have an entry in Paper.  THe inner join excludes those without papers or entries in author.

Comment: `JOIN` without specifics is an `INNER JOIN`, only returning the results that satisfy the condition. A `LEFT JOIN` would include results from the initial table with a `null` for the joined table (when they don't match the condition), which you can `COALESCE` to change the `null` count to `0`.

Comment: As to the 2nd question: `having count(*) > 1` to ensure they worked on more than 1 paper together.  and you'd need to group by the fields in your select.

Comment: One last resource: [CodingHorror on SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: The WHERE AU.PANUM = PA.PANUM condition is already in the ON clause. Skip the WHERE one.

Comment: Got it to work, thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

This addresses the first question; you should only be asking one question at a time.

What you want is a `LEFT JOIN`.  Also, I don't think you need the `PAPER` table:

```
SELECT A.ACNUM, COUNT(AU.PANUM)
FROM ACADEMIC A LEFT JOIN
     AUTHOR AU
     ON A.ACNUM = AU.ACNUM 
GROUP BY A.ACNUM
ORDER BY A.ACNUM;
```